# adding any unix timestamp in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, unix-timestamp

i want to add unix timestamp in the giveaway time like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBHuF.png)

here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def giveaway(ctx, days:int, hours:int, minutes:int, seconds:int, prize:str):
  time = days + hours + minutes + seconds
  embed = discord.Embed(title=prize, description=f"time: <t:{time}:R>")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=time)
  endembed = discord.Embed(title=f"you have won {prize}", description="The time has ended")
  await ctx.send(embed=endembed)
```

when I run the code it shows me this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhk1n.png)

Comment: As you mentioned yourself: You need a timestamp of the exact date. You would have to convert it yourself if you want to keep the `days, hours...` argument(s).

Comment: Ok, you've done exactly that: you've added a timestamp to an embed. If you can [edit] your question to include what exactly the problem is, it would help us understand exactly what you're looking for. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `mktime` function in the time module.

```py
import datetime
import time

def convert_to_unix_time(date: datetime.datetime, days: int, hours: int, minutes: int, seconds: int) -> str:
    # Get the end date
    end_date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=days, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)

    # Get a tuple of the date attributes
    date_tuple = (end_date.year, end_date.month, end_date.day, end_date.hour, end_date.minute, end_date.second)

    # Convert to unix time
    return f'<t:{int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(*date_tuple).timetuple()))}:R>'
```

The returned value should like somewhat like this: `<t:1655392367:R>`

Pasting the returned string will give a dynamic display as shown in the image you have provided.

The `mktime` function returns a float value. For the datetime to be displayed dynamically, the value in between must be numbers only.

The `R` in the end of the returned string stands for `relative`. The dynamic display will be relative to current time. [The other formats are `t`, `T`, `d`, `D`, `f` and `F`.](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-timestamp-styles)

Comment: i get it now but how can i implement it in my code?

Comment: You should be able to simply use `end_date.timestamp()`.

Comment: @GameProgrammer, the returned string can be used as the description for the embed.



`embed = discord.Embed(title=prize, description=f"time: <t:{convert_to_unix_time(date, days, hours, minutes, seconds)}:R>")`